# Cannot import maven project to eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

when i try to import existing maven project to eclipse i get this error

"The selected wizard could not be started.
Plug-in org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenImportWizard.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui (281)."

using eclipse luna
windows 10 - 64